# calling a function from another function by 'onclick' event

Tags: javascript

What I am trying to do is, call a function from another function by clicking a radio button in that function. Here is the code I have worked on so far-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
rad1 = document.createElement("input");
rad1.type = "radio";
rad1.name = "dooropt";
rad1.id = "rb1";
rad1.value = "y";
newP.appendChild(rad1);
text1 = document.createTextNode("Yes ");
newP.appendChild(text1);
rad2 = document.createElement("input");
rad2.type = "radio";
rad2.name = "dooropt";
rad2.id = "rb2";
rad2.value = "n";
newP.appendChild(rad2);
text2 = document.createTextNode("No ");
newP.appendChild(text2);
button1 = document.createElement("input");
button1.type = "button";
button1.value = "Open main door";
button1.style.visibility = "hidden";
newP.appendChild(button1);
button2 = document.createElement("input");
button2.type = "button";
button2.value = "Open apartment door";
button2.style.visibility = "hidden";
newP.appendChild(button2);
area.appendChild(newP);
rad1.onclick = mainalso();
rad2.onclick = onlyapp();
}

 function mainalso()
{ 
    button1.style.visibility="visible";
    button2.style.visibility="visible";
    }

 function onlyapp()
{
    button2.style.visibility="visible";
    button1.style.visibility="hidden";
    }
</script>
```

Now, whenever rad1 is clicked, i want mainalso() to run, as might be clear from the code. Since I am fairly new to JavaScript, I don't know where i'm making the mistake, in syntax or conceptually. Also, the first function (before mainalso()) is add(), and in it I repeatedly append same content on clicking a button in my body. I hope it is clear what I want to do. When rad1 is clicked, i want both buttons (button1 and button2) to appear, but on clicking rad2 I want only one button to appear. Both have been set to 'hidden' visibility at first.
Please help me out. Sorry if it seems unclear, I tried my best..
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing:

```
rad1.onclick = mainalso();
rad2.onclick = onlyapp();
```

To:

```
rad1.onclick = mainalso;
rad2.onclick = onlyapp;
```

As it stands you're assigning the result of calling the `function`s to the `onclick` of `rad1` and `rad2` which in this case will be `undefined`. By removing the `()` you will assign the `function` correctly.

To ensure that `button1` and `button2` are available and set to the correct value when your `function` is called you could change the code to:

```
...
newP.appendChild(button2);
area.appendChild(newP);
(function (b1, b2) {
    rad1.onclick = function () {
        b1.style.visibility="visible";
        b2.style.visibility="visible";
    };
    rad2.onclick = function () {
        b2.style.visibility="visible";
        b1.style.visibility="hidden";
    };
})(button1, button2);
```

Comment: did that. still doesn't work. Is there something wrong with the mainalso() and onlyapp() functions?

Comment: The `mainalso()` and `onlyapp()` `function`s will only work correctly if `button1` and `button2` are in the global scope; is that the case?

Comment: no, they are created in function add() previous to the mainalso(), since i want them to be appended on each click of a button. How can i fix that?

Comment: should i declare them outside, globally, but define them inside the function add()? will that work?

Comment: If `button1` and `button2` only ever have one value then this would be fine. If you're assigning them in a loop then you'd run into issues with closures. I've updated my answer to show the way I would do it.

Comment: but when i click yes or no, only the most recent buttons disappear.. no matter what radio button is clicked.. (previous or current). any comments?

Comment: sorry, my mistake. Have updated the code. This is to do with [closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Closures).

Answer (score 1):

You should do this:

```
rad1.onclick = mainalso;
rad2.onclick = onlyapp;
```

Edit: I tried this and it works for me. See [example](http://jsfiddle.net/BU4PW/)

```
window.onload = function() {
rad1 = document.createElement("input");
rad1.type = "radio";
rad1.name = "dooropt";
rad1.id = "rb1";
rad1.value = "y";
newP.appendChild(rad1);
text1 = document.createTextNode("Yes ");
newP.appendChild(text1);
rad2 = document.createElement("input");
rad2.type = "radio";
rad2.name = "dooropt";
rad2.id = "rb2";
rad2.value = "n";
newP.appendChild(rad2);
text2 = document.createTextNode("No ");
newP.appendChild(text2);
button1 = document.createElement("input");
button1.type = "button";
button1.value = "Open main door";
button1.style.visibility = "hidden";
newP.appendChild(button1);
button2 = document.createElement("input");
button2.type = "button";
button2.value = "Open apartment door";
button2.style.visibility = "hidden";
newP.appendChild(button2);
area.appendChild(newP);
rad1.onclick = mainalso();
rad2.onclick = onlyapp();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to define newP and area that you are using : 
area.appendChild(newP);

As the tag HTML is used like  this :

```
<input  type="radio" name="dooropt" id="rb1" value="y" onClick="mainalso()"/>
```

So you can use :

rad1.onClick=mainalso;